# Hablitar errores en PHP

Tags: php, iis

Desinstalé XAMPP para instalar PHP en IIS pero me doy cuenta que los errores no están habilitados. Cuando ocurre algún error de sintáxis o algún otro tipo de error en el código la página no lo notifica y simplemente manda un error 500.

¿De que manera puedo habilitar los errores en PHP? Ya sea warnings, errores y demás.

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1053424/1983854

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dentro de tu archivo al inicio agrega:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(-1);
...
...
...
?>
```

puedes ver el significado de las directivas de configuración [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/function.error-reporting.php) en la documentación en español:

http://php.net/manual/es/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Gracias, lo logre poniendo la linea de display_errors en ON

Comment: Excellent, para más especifico agregue el link de la información en español : http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

Answer (score 0):

Yo siempre utilizo esto:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma más facil es:

```
error_reporting(-1);
```

o también poniendo lo siguiente en tu **php.ini**:

```
display_errors = On
```